# How to create an Android Lollipop "Delightful transition"

Tags: android, material-design

Here is video demo how it looks like :
[Delightful transition video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-delightfulDetails-statusChange-example_large_xhdpi.webm)

I want to make a similar in my project, the PLAY->PAUSE one.

I guess it's something to do with `AnimatedStateListDrawable` but can't figure it out.

Comment: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2014/11/13/transitioning-to-infinity/

Comment: @timothyjc Thanks, it really seems helpful